# How do I ensure that the url of my image in flutter doesn't show up on the screen instead of the image?

Tags: flutter, listview, search, assets, imageurl

I am new to flutter. I was trying to get the pictures of some plants to show up beside the name of the specific plant however I was getting the url instead, is there any possible way that i can fix this issue in my code down below?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  // This holds a list of fiction users
  // You can use data fetched from a database or a server as well
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allHerbs = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "plant1",
      "urlImage":
          'https://www.southernexposure.com/media/products/originals/sweet-genovese-basil-809aaf7e3d9a3f3fa7ce2f0eb4480e95.jpg'
    },
    {"id": 2, "name": "plant2", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 3, "name": "plant3", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 4, "name": "plant4", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 5, "name": "plant5", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 6, "name": "plant6", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 7, "name": "plant7", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 8, "name": "plant8", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 9, "name": "plant9", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 10, "name": "plant10", "urlImage": ''},
  ];

  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundHerbs = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    _foundHerbs = _allHerbs;
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = _allHerbs;
    } else {
      results = _allHerbs
          .where((user) =>
              user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _foundHerbs = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Herb Search'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _foundHerbs.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _foundHerbs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                        key: ValueKey(_foundHerbs[index]["id"]),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        elevation: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            _foundHerbs[index]["id"].toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_foundHerbs[index]['name']),
                          subtitle: Text('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]} '),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'No results found',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting to get image from text widget you just need to

change this

```
subtitle: Text('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]} '),
```

to this

```
subtitle: Image.network('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]} '),
```

the above will show your image under the title but if you want to show it beside use the leading or trailing instead of subtitle

like this

```
leading: Image.network('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]} '),
```

Comment: How would i display information about an image when it is clicked?

Comment: List tile has on tap feature so you can use that and pass the content to show more info